# SPHINX SE : Fetching Records Issue

Tags: sphinx

In SphinSE, i can fetch any records from sphinx server.

Example :
  I having following records:

```
Id  Name      Item   Price
1   karthik   Car     1000
2   Car       karthik 200
```

To Fetching records, i have used following query

select * from indexname WHERE query='karthik;mode=any';

```
   It has return 2 records. How can i get record, which record having Name AS karthik using SPHINXSE. Please suggest
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from indexname WHERE query='@Name karthik;mode=extended';
```

or maybe

```
select * from indexname WHERE query='@Name "^karthik$ ";mode=extended';
```